# Matlab storing data in column or row

Tags: matlab

I have written a algorithm, storing the data points in column. The results contains `mean` and `std`. However, if I store the data points in row instead, the results seem more close to the true value. Is there a proper explanation to this? In my opinion, the results should be independent from the way of storage and thus remain the same.

```
function [C]=test(n,m)
  rng default
  B=randn(m,n)
  rng default
  A=randn(n,m)
  C=A'-B
end
```

I am using this generator to do my calculations. My results turns out to be different depending on if I use `randn(m,n)` or `randn(n,m)`. (I am taking m-th column or m-row to sum them up cumulatively).

Comment: It would be nice if you show us the data. what kind of difference you are observing.

Comment: @User1551892 Unfortunately this is part of my project with plagiarism disclosure. If I post the data and code, I am afraid the plagiarism quote will increase. Is there a way to post alternative datas?

Comment: of course, just post sample made up data, it does not have to be the exact data of your project. Make the sample small also. More advice on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @quallenjäger: randn always generate the new values. I think, you should reshape the Matrix B. So A should be reshaped version of B.

Comment: @User1551892 How to reshape?

Comment: @quallenjäger: A = reshape (B, n,m) ;